# Haskell Polyvariadic Function With IO

Tags: haskell, ffi, polyvariadic

Is it possible to have a function that takes a foreign function call where some of the foreign function's arguments are CString and return a function that accepts String instead?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
 foreign_func_1 :: (CDouble -> CString -> IO())
 foreign_func_2 :: (CDouble -> CDouble -> CString -> IO ())

 externalFunc1 :: (Double -> String -> IO())
 externalFunc1 = myFunc foreign_func_1

 externalFunc2 :: (Double -> Double -> String -> IO())
 externalFunc2 = myFunc foreign_func_2
```

I figured out how to do this with the C numeric types.  However,  I can't figure out a way to do it that can allow string conversion.

The problem seems to be fitting in IO functions, since everything that converts to CStrings such as newCString or withCString are IO.

Here is what the code looks like to just handle converting doubles.

```
class CConvertable interiorArgs exteriorArgs where
   convertArgs :: (Ptr OtherIrrelevantType -> interiorArgs) -> exteriorArgs

instance CConvertable (IO ()) (Ptr OtherIrrelevantType -> IO ()) where
   convertArgs = doSomeOtherThingsThatArentCausingProblems
instance (Real b, Fractional a, CConvertable intArgs extArgs) => CConvertable (a->intArgs) (b->extArgs) where
    convertArgs op x= convertArgs (\ctx -> op ctx (realToFrac x))
```

Comment: Can you show us what you did write?

Comment: This is a pretty messy job :-) I'd imagine the answer if it exists is too painful for real use. Have you looked at `hsc2hs`? It's quite powerful, and can generate the sorts of signatures that you'd like as a preprocessing step.

Comment: One solution I've been considering is to make something like a convertNth function, which would take a number and a function, and do the conversion to that position.  I think I sort of get how that would work, though I haven't tried it yet, so maybe it would present some difficulty I haven't thought of.  The plus side would be that I'd still be able to use my existing function for non-strings and only have to explicitly call out strings.   Ideally, of course, I or someone else would just figure out how to automatically handle the strings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a function that takes a foreign function call where some of the foreign function's arguments are CString and return a function that accepts String instead?

Is it possible, you ask?

```
<lambdabot> The answer is: Yes! Haskell can do that.
```

Ok. Good thing we got that cleared up.

Warming up with a few tedious formalities:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

Ah, it's not so bad though. Look, ma, no overlaps!

> The problem seems to be fitting in IO functions, since everything that converts to CStrings such as newCString or withCString are IO.

Right. The thing to observe here is that there are two somewhat interrelated matters with which to concern ourselves: A correspondence between two types, allowing conversions; and any extra context introduced by performing a conversion. To deal with this fully, we'll make both parts explicit and shuffle them around appropriately. We also need to take heed of *variance*; lifting an entire function requires working with types in both covariant and contravariant position, so we'll need conversions going in both directions.

Now, given a function we wish to translate, the plan goes something like this:

- Convert the function's argument, receiving a new type and some context.
- Defer the context onto the function's result, to get the argument how we want it.
- Collapse redundant contexts where possible
- Recursively translate the function's result, to deal with multi-argument functions

Well, that doesn't sound too difficult. First, explicit contexts:

```hs
class (Functor f, Cxt t ~ f) => Context (f :: * -> *) t where
    type Collapse t :: *
    type Cxt t :: * -> *
    collapse :: t -> Collapse t
```

This says we have a context `f`, and some type `t` with that context. The `Cxt` type function extracts the plain context from `t`, and `Collapse` tries to combine contexts if possible. The `collapse` function lets us use the result of the type function.

For now, we have pure contexts, and `IO`:

```hs
newtype PureCxt a = PureCxt { unwrapPure :: a }

instance Context IO (IO (PureCxt a)) where
    type Collapse (IO (PureCxt a)) = IO a
    type Cxt (IO (PureCxt a)) = IO
    collapse = fmap unwrapPure

{- more instances here... -}
```

Simple enough. Handling various combinations of contexts is a bit tedious, but the instances are obvious and easy to write.

We'll also need a way to determine the context given a type to convert. Currently the context is the same going in either direction, but it's certainly conceivable for it to be otherwise, so I've treated them separately. Thus, we have two type families, supplying the new outermost context for an import/export conversion:

```hs
type family ExpCxt int :: * -> *
type family ImpCxt ext :: * -> *
```

Some example instances:

```hs
type instance ExpCxt () = PureCxt
type instance ImpCxt () = PureCxt

type instance ExpCxt String = IO
type instance ImpCxt CString = IO
```

Next up, converting individual types. We'll worry about recursion later. Time for another type class:

```hs
class (Foreign int ~ ext, Native ext ~ int) => Convert ext int where
    type Foreign int :: *
    type Native ext :: *
    toForeign :: int -> ExpCxt int ext
    toNative :: ext -> ImpCxt ext int
```

This says that two types `ext` and `int` are uniquely convertible to each other. I realize that it might not be desirable to always have only one mapping for each type, but I didn't feel like complicating things further (at least, not right now).

As noted, I've also put off handling recursive conversions here; probably they could be combined, but I felt it would be clearer this way. Non-recursive conversions have simple, well-defined mappings that introduce a corresponding context, while recursive conversions need to propagate and merge contexts and deal with distinguishing recursive steps from the base case.

Oh, and you may have noticed by now the funny wiggly tilde business going on up there in the class contexts. That indicates a constraint that the two types must be equal; in this case it ties each type function to the opposite type parameter, which gives the bidirectional nature mentioned above. Er, you probably want to have a fairly recent GHC, though. On older GHCs, this would need functional dependencies instead, and would be written as something like `class Convert ext int | ext -> int, int -> ext`.

The term-level conversion functions are pretty simple--note the type function application in their result; application is left-associative as always, so that's just applying the context from the earlier type families. Also note the cross-over in names, in that the *export* context comes from a lookup using the *native* type.

So, we can convert types that don't need `IO`:

```hs
instance Convert CDouble Double where
    type Foreign Double = CDouble
    type Native CDouble = Double
    toForeign = pure . realToFrac
    toNative = pure . realToFrac
```

...as well as types that do:

```hs
instance Convert CString String where
    type Foreign String = CString
    type Native CString = String
    toForeign = newCString
    toNative = peekCString
```

Now to strike at the heart of the matter, and translate whole functions recursively. It should come as no surprise that I've introduced *yet another* type class. Actually, two, as I've separated import/export conversions this time.

```hs
class FFImport ext where
    type Import ext :: *
    ffImport :: ext -> Import ext

class FFExport int where
    type Export int :: *
    ffExport :: int -> Export int
```

Nothing interesting here. You may be noticing a common pattern by now--we're doing roughly equal amounts of computing at both the term and type level, and we're doing them in tandem, even to the point of mimicking names and expression structure. This is pretty common if you're doing type-level calculation for things involving real values, since GHC gets fussy if it doesn't understand what you're doing. Lining things up like this reduces headaches significantly.

Anyway, for each of these classes, we need one instance for each possible base case, and one for the recursive case. Alas, we can't easily have a generic base case, due to the usual bothersome nonsense with overlapping. It could be done using fundeps and type equality conditionals, but... ugh. Maybe later. Another option would be to parameterize the conversion function by a type-level number giving the desired conversion depth, which has the downside of being less automatic, but gains some benefit from being explicit as well, such as being less likely to stumble on polymorphic or ambiguous types.

For now, I'm going to assume that every function ends with something in `IO`, since `IO a` is distinguishable from `a -> b` without overlap.

First, the base case:

```hs
instance ( Context IO (IO (ImpCxt a (Native a)))
         , Convert a (Native a)
         ) => FFImport (IO a) where
    type Import (IO a) = Collapse (IO (ImpCxt a (Native a)))
    ffImport x = collapse $ toNative <$> x
```

The constraints here assert a specific context using a known instance, and that we have some base type with a conversion. Again, note the parallel structure shared by the type function `Import` and term function `ffImport`. The actual idea here should be pretty obvious--we map the conversion function over `IO`, creating a nested context of some sort, then use `Collapse`/`collapse` to clean up afterwards.

The recursive case is similar, but more elaborate:

```hs
instance ( FFImport b, Convert a (Native a)
         , Context (ExpCxt (Native a)) (ExpCxt (Native a) (Import b))
         ) => FFImport (a -> b) where
    type Import (a -> b) = Native a -> Collapse (ExpCxt (Native a) (Import b))
    ffImport f x = collapse $ ffImport . f <$> toForeign x
```

We've added an `FFImport` constraint for the recursive call, and the context wrangling has gotten more awkward because we don't know exactly what it is, merely specifying enough to make sure we can deal with it. Note also the contravariance here, in that we're converting the *function* to native types, but converting the *argument* to a foreign type. Other than that, it's still pretty simple.

Now, I've left out some instances at this point, but everything else follows the same patterns as the above, so let's just skip to the end and scope out the goods. Some imaginary foreign functions:

```hs
foreign_1 :: (CDouble -> CString -> CString -> IO ())
foreign_1 = undefined

foreign_2 :: (CDouble -> SizedArray a -> IO CString)
foreign_2 = undefined
```

And conversions:

```hs
imported1 = ffImport foreign_1
imported2 = ffImport foreign_2
```

What, no type signatures? Did it work?

```hs
> :t imported1
imported1 :: Double -> String -> [Char] -> IO ()
> :t imported2
imported2 :: Foreign.Storable.Storable a => Double -> AsArray a -> IO [Char]
```

Yep, that's the *inferred* type. Ah, that's what I like to see.

**Edit**: For anyone who wants to try this out, I've taken the full code for the demonstration here, cleaned it up a bit, and [uploaded it to github](https://github.com/isomorphism/evangelist).

Comment: Nice! Two issues though -- since you're just using `newCString` and not `withCString`, this will leak like an unnamed source at the pentagon. Second, without undecidable instances, I'm assuming this code also can't default to let through arbitrary values (without convert instances) unchanged?

Comment: @sclv: Good point about the allocation--using `withCString` actually makes for an interesting example, as well. As for default instances, that's only possible in the general case with *overlapping* instances and, hence, fundeps. Undecidable instances are already needed for the recursion in `Import` and a few others.

Comment: Yep -- mixed up my undecidable and overlapping.

Comment: @sclv: Keep in mind that I was intentionally avoiding overlapping, and fundeps as a whole, specifically to illustrate type families and how much nicer they are for things like this. At least, I think they're nicer, with the symmetry between the type and term functions.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with template haskell. In many ways it is simpler than the
alternatives involving classes, since it is easier pattern match on
Language.Haskell.TH.Type than do the same thing with instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
--  test.hs
import FFiImport
import Foreign.C

foreign_1 :: CDouble -> CString -> CString -> IO CString
foreign_2 :: CDouble -> CString -> CString -> IO (Int,CString)
foreign_3 :: CString -> IO ()

foreign_1 = undefined; foreign_2 = undefined; foreign_3 = undefined

fmap concat (mapM ffimport ['foreign_1, 'foreign_2, 'foreign_3])
```

Inferred types of the generated functions are:

```
imported_foreign_1 :: Double -> String -> String -> IO String
imported_foreign_2 :: Double -> String -> String -> IO (Int, String)
imported_foreign_3 :: String -> IO ()
```

Checking the generated code by loading test.hs with -ddump-splices (note that
ghc still seems to miss some parentheses in the pretty printing) shows that
foreign_2 writes a definition which after some prettying up looks like:

```
imported_foreign_2 w x y
  = (\ (a, b) -> ((return (,) `ap` return a) `ap` peekCString b) =<<
     join
       (((return foreign_2 `ap`
          (return . (realToFrac :: Double -> CDouble)) w) `ap`
         newCString x) `ap`
        newCString y))
```

or translated to do notation:

```
imported_foreign_2 w x y = do
       w2 <- return . (realToFrac :: Double -> CDouble) w
       x2 <- newCString x
       y2 <- newCString y
       (a,b) <- foreign_2 w2 x2 y2
       a2 <- return a
       b2 <- peekCString b
       return (a2,b2)
```

Generating code the first way is simpler in that there are less variables to
track. While foldl ($) f [x,y,z] doesn't type check when it would mean
((f $ x) $ y $ z) = f x y z
it's acceptable in template haskell which involves only a handful of different
types.

Now for the actual implementation of those ideas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
-- FFiImport.hs
module FFiImport(ffimport) where
import Language.Haskell.TH; import Foreign.C; import Control.Monad

-- a couple utility definitions

-- args (a -> b -> c -> d) = [a,b,c]
args (AppT (AppT ArrowT x) y) = x : args y
args _ = []

-- result (a -> b -> c -> d) = d
result (AppT (AppT ArrowT _) y) = result y
result y = y

-- con (IO a) = IO
-- con (a,b,c,d) = TupleT 4
con (AppT x _) = con x
con x = x

-- conArgs (a,b,c,d) = [a,b,c,d]
-- conArgs (Either a b) = [a,b]
conArgs ty = go ty [] where
    go (AppT x y) acc = go x (y:acc)
    go _ acc = acc
```

The splice $(ffimport 'foreign_2) looks at the type of foreign_2 with reify to
decide on which functions to apply to the arguments or result.

```
-- Possibly useful to parameterize based on conv'
ffimport :: Name -> Q [Dec]
ffimport n = do
    VarI _ ntype _ _ <- reify n

    let ty :: [Type]
        ty = args ntype

    let -- these define conversions
        --   (ffiType, (hsType -> IO ffiType, ffiType -> IO hsType))
        conv' :: [(TypeQ, (ExpQ, ExpQ))]
        conv' = [
            ([t| CString |], ([| newCString |],
                              [| peekCString |])),
            ([t| CDouble |], ([| return . (realToFrac :: Double -> CDouble) |],
                              [| return . (realToFrac :: CDouble -> Double) |]))
            ]

        sequenceFst :: Monad m => [(m a, b)] -> m [(a,b)]
        sequenceFst x = liftM (`zip` map snd x) (mapM fst x)

    conv' <- sequenceFst conv'
    -- now    conv' :: [(Type, (ExpQ, ExpQ))]
```

Given conv' above, it's somewhat straightforward to apply those functions when
the types match. The back case would be shorter if converting components of
returned tuples wasn't important.

```
    let conv :: Type -- ^ type of v
             -> Name -- ^ variable to be converted
             -> ExpQ
        conv t v
            | Just (to,from) <- lookup t conv' =
                [| $to $(varE v) |]
            | otherwise = [| return $(varE v) |]

        -- | function to convert result types back, either
        --  occuring as IO a, IO (a,b,c)   (for any tuple size)
        back :: ExpQ
        back
            |   AppT _ rty <- result ntype,
                TupleT n <- con rty,
                n > 0, -- for whatever reason   $(conE (tupleDataName 0))
                       -- doesn't work when it could just be  $(conE '())
                convTup <- map (maybe [| return |] snd .
                                    flip lookup conv')
                                    (conArgs rty)
                                 = do
                    rs <- replicateM n (newName "r")
                    lamE [tupP (map varP rs)]
                        [| $(foldl (\f x -> [| $f `ap` $x |])
                              [| return $(conE (tupleDataName n)) |]
                              (zipWith (\c r -> [| $c $(varE r)|]) convTup rs))
                        |]
            |   AppT _ nty <- result ntype,
                Just (_,from) <- nty `lookup` conv' = from
            | otherwise = [| return |]
```

Finally, put both parts together in a function definition:

```
    vs <- replicateM (length ty) (newName "v")

    liftM (:[]) $
        funD (mkName $ "imported_"++nameBase n)
         [clause
            (map varP vs)
            (normalB [| $back =<< join
                        $(foldl (\x y -> [| $x `ap` $y |])
                                [| return $(varE n) |]
                                (zipWith conv ty vs))
                |])
            []]
```

Comment: Nice! Good to see worked examples of doing things with TH. In many ways I prefer type classes for things like this, where conceptually it really is a function on types that carries the terms along, but as you point out, TH makes some parts easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a horrible two typeclass solution. The first part (named, unhelpfully, `foo`) will take things of types like `Double -> Double -> CString -> IO ()` and turn them into things like `IO (Double -> IO (Double -> IO (String -> IO ())))`. So each conversion is forced into IO just to keep things fully uniform.

The second part, (named `cio` for "collapse io) will take those things and shove all the `IO` bits to the end.

```
class Foo a b | a -> b where
    foo :: a -> b
instance Foo (IO a) (IO a) where
    foo = id
instance Foo a (IO b) => Foo (CString -> a) (IO (String -> IO b)) where
    foo f = return $ \s -> withCString s $ \cs -> foo (f cs)
instance Foo a (IO b) => Foo (Double -> a) (IO (Double -> IO b)) where
    foo f = return $ \s -> foo (f s)

class CIO a b | a -> b where
    cio :: a -> b
instance CIO (IO ()) (IO ()) where
    cio = id
instance CIO (IO b) c => CIO (IO (a -> IO b)) (a -> c) where
    cio f = \a -> cio $ f >>= ($ a)

{-
*Main> let x = foo (undefined :: Double -> Double -> CString -> IO ())
*Main> :t x
x :: IO (Double -> IO (Double -> IO (String -> IO ())))
*Main> :t cio x
cio x :: Double -> Double -> String -> IO ()
-}
```

Aside from being a generally terrible thing to do, there are two specific limitations. The first is that a catchall instance of `Foo` can't be written. So for every type you want to convert, even if the conversion is just `id`, you need an instance of `Foo`. The second limitation is that a catchall base case of `CIO` can't be written because of the `IO` wrappers around everything. So this only works for things that return `IO ()`. If you want it to work for something returning `IO Int` you need to add that instance too.

I suspect that with sufficient work and some typeCast trickery these limitations can be overcome. But the code is horrible enough as is, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible.  The usual approach is to create lambdas to pass to `withCString`.  Using your example:

```
myMarshaller :: (CDouble -> CString -> IO ()) -> CDouble -> String -> IO ()
myMarshaller func cdouble string = ...

withCString :: String -> (CString -> IO a) -> IO a
```

The inner function has type `CString -> IO a`, which is exactly the type after applying a `CDouble` to the C function `func`.  You've got a `CDouble` in scope too, so that's everything you need.

```
myMarshaller func cdouble string =
  withCString string (\cstring -> func cdouble cstring)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I'm trying to get a function that accepts an unspecified number of arguments.  I've updated the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  That's harder, but not impossible.